# Issues parsing textual data

Tags: python, parsing

I have a text file that I want to parse and output to a csv. The data comes from SSURGO soil metadata (USDA). I have converted the pdf that describes the database tables, column names, and descriptions into a text file and would like to convert to a csv.

The column values are:

```
Table Physical Name:
Table Label:
Column Physical name:
Column Label:
Desc:
```

Sometimes the Column physical name and column label do not include a description. Example input file is:

```
Table Physical Name: chaashto
Table Label: Horizon AASHTO
Column Physical Name: aashtocl 
Column Label:   AASHTO
desc: Some description here.
```

Not every column name and label has a corresponding desc: or Table Physical Name and Label.

I have parsed the data to have one row for each column Physical Name and Label using the following code:

```
count = 0
cnt = 0 
out = open("output_test.txt", "wb")
value1,value2,value3,value4,value5 = "","","","","" 
for i,line in enumerate(lines):

    key, value = line.strip().split(':',1)
    if key == 'Table Physical Name':
        value1 = value.strip()
    if key == 'Table Label':
        value2 = value.strip()
    if key == 'Column Physical Name':
        value3 = value.strip()
    if key == 'Column Label':
        value4 = value.strip()
        if not lines[i+1].strip().startswith('desc'):
            count = 1
    if key == 'desc':
        value5 = value.strip()
        count = 1
    if count == 1:
        cnt += 1
        record = value1 + ";" +value2 + ";" + value3 + ";" + value4 + ";" + value5 +";\n"
        print cnt, record
        out.write(record)
        count = 0
        value3 = " "
        value4 = " "
        value5 = " "
    out.close()
```

(Pardon the sloppy-looking code, just learning Python).

At any rate, the issue is that sometimes when a line is output it does not include the Column Physical Name and inserts a \r at the end of the line. The subsequent line then includes the key "Column Physical Name: "Name of Column"

This is how the output should look:

```
chfrags;Horizon Fragments;chfragskey;Chorizon Fragments Key;A non-connotative string of characters used to uniquely identify a record in the Horizon Fragments table.;
```

This is how the "bad" output looks:

```
coforprodo;Component Forest Productivity - Other; ;Low
Column Physical Name: fprod_r; ;
```

In the above example, "fprod_r" should be between Other; and ";Low" and the "\r" after ;Low should not be there.

The maddening thing is that when I subset the input file, the places where the errors occur no longer occur. So the code processes the text file correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to do all the *CSV* ETL by hand. *Python* has a module `csv` for that which you can leverage, and which should help to eliminate the sort of edge cases you're encountering.

You might try something like this:

```
import csv

with open('foo.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerow(('Table Physical Name', 'Table Label', 'Column Physical Name', 'Column Label', 'Desc'))
    writer.writerow( ('chfrags', 'Horizon Fragments', 'chfragskey', 'Chorizon Fragments Key',
                      'A non-connotative string of characters used to uniquely identify a record in the Horizon Fragments table.')
                   )
```

Which outputs this:

```
"Table Physical Name","Table Label","Column Physical Name","Column Label","Desc"
"chfrags","Horizon Fragments","chfragskey","Chorizon Fragments Key","A non-connotative string of characters used to uniquely identify a record in the Horizon Fragments table."
```

You may need to tweak this code somewhat to meet your exact data needs (i.e. the delimiter, the type of quoting, and the exact details of the row *tuples*) but this should provide the general template, using the data you mentioned above, for you to use.

Answer (score 1):

All, I apologize. There were "invisible" \r that were not showing up when i was using notepad++. Not sure why, but when I finally deleted them, the output is correct. Not sure why the \r were not carried over into the subset file. Oh well.